# Biblatex - hyphen between author names when using citet

Tags: biblatex, citing, biber

I cite elements from my bibfile using `\citet{key}`. The reference appears as "Name1, and Name2 (year)" in text where year is a link leading to the bibliography. Now, instead of the "and" between the the authors name, I want to use a **hyphen**, e.g.

> The Name1-Name2 (2019) formula implies ...

Any ideas of I could adjust the `\citet` command?

---

I use `biblatex` as follows.

```
\usepackage[style=ext-authoryear-comp,
            backend=biber,
            natbib=true,
            uniquename=false,
            uniquelist=false,
            giveninits=false,
            dashed=false,
            backref=false,
            maxbibnames=99,
            maxcitenames=3,
            isbn=false,
            doi=false]{biblatex}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `\DeclareDelimFormat` you can change the delimiter between names per citation command.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=ext-authoryear-comp, natbib=true]{biblatex}

\DeclareDelimFormat[textcite]{multinamedelim}{\textendash}
\DeclareDelimAlias[textcite]{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}

The \textcite{sigfridsson} formula

The \citet{sigfridsson} formula

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: The Sigfridsson–Ryde (1998) formula]

---

I'd probably prefer to define a new cite command for this so that `\textcite` is still usable as normal.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=ext-authoryear-comp, natbib=true]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\attribcite}{%
  \AtNextCite{%
    \DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\textendash}%
    \DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}%
  }%
  \textcite}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}

The \attribcite{sigfridsson} formula

As shown by \textcite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: The Sigfridsson–Ryde (1998) formula//As shown by Sigfridsson and Ryde (1998)]

Comment: As always, thank you so much. You're fantastic! :)